# Reason for ordering of answers where none is accepted

Tags: support, answers, sorting

A recent question has 3 answers, no answer has been upvoted, no answer has been downvoted and my answer is on top even though my answer wasn't the first and the other guys who answered have more rep. Is it because I have more badges?

Comment: I'll go with @Rob's answer. What I've found is when this criteria (no up/down votes, nothing accepted) happens to a question with multiple answers, the **latest** answer posted usually comes out on top. (But I rarely refresh!)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The ordering is random. Refresh the page a few times, and you'll see the order of answers changes. Also, you have an insane amount of badges for your rep level, nice work!

Comment: Insane indeed... o.o

Comment: @Seth & Rob: [bounties ...](http://stackoverflow.com/users/108207/dac-saunders?tab=bounties). Still, good job.

Comment: I'd say they have an insanely low reputation (even after bounties) for the number of question-view-badges they have. It's like out of those 10k people that view questions in the google-app-engine tag hardly anyone ever votes.